# How to create a JS Array containing an JS Object as Key value pairs from string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I Have a javascript code

```
var jsString1 = [];
var jsString = [];
var val1, val2;
val1 = "test1";
val2 = "test2";
jsString1.push("key1");
jsString1.push(val1);
jsString1.push("key2");
jsString1.push(val2);
jsString.push(jsString1);
alert(JSON.stringify(jsString));
```

this will give the result as these

```
// current output
 [["key1","test1","key2","test2"]]
```

but I need to make one like these

```
// needed output
 [{"key1":"test1","key2":"test2"}]
```

How can I do it ? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would only do

```js
jsString1.push({
    "key1": val1 "key2": val2
})
```

Your code only pushes into the array.

You need to create an object first, and then add the object into the array.

Comment: its not pushing values in the above format

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of arrays of keys and values `[[key, value, key, value]]`. If the array was in the form of `[[key, value], [key, value], ...]` (entries) we could use `Object.fromEntries()` to convert it to an object.

To transform the original an array of entries, map the array, use `Array.from()` to convert sub-arrays to tuples of `[key, value]`, and then use `Array.flat()` to convert the 3d array to a 2d array of entries:

```js
const toEntries = arr =>
  arr.map(subArr => 
    Array.from({ length: subArr.length / 2 }, (_, i) => 
      subArr.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2)
    )
  ).flat(1)

const arr = [["key1","test1","key2","test2"]];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(toEntries(arr))

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: How to add the 3rd key and its value ?

Comment: Push them to `jsString1` array.

Comment: @Gopipuli any reason you can't just create an object an push it into an array? It seems like you're over-complicating things.